# how to apply background color for search highlited words Jquery DataTable

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a grid view control in that columns have header html textbox using for search when i am searching grid view items i need to apply color for that how can i apply color for searching words.

My code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Element" Visible="true" HeaderStyle-Width="30%" ItemStyle-Width="30%">
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        Speciality<br><input name="DynamicTextBox" id="txtElement" type="text" style="width: 120px" placeholder="Search Speciality" />
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblElement" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Element") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField> 



    <script>       
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %>').hide();
                var values = eval('<%=Values%>');
                var InfoVal = localStorage.getItem("Info");            
                DataTable();
                SearchValue(values);
                $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %>').show();
            });
            function bindDataTable(value) {

                $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %> th').each(function () {
                    var title = $(this).text();
                    if (title == "Name" || title == "PName" || title == "Element") {
                        if (title == "Name"  || title == "PName") {
                            title1 = title.replace(" ", "");
                        }
                        if (title == "Element") {
                            title1 = title;
                        }
                        $(this).html(title + '<br/><input  name = "DynamicTextBox" id="txt' + title1 + '" type="text" style="width:120px" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).html(title + '<br/><br/>  ');
                    }
                });
            };
            var table;
            function DataTable() {
                table = $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %>').prepend($('<thead></thead>').append($('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %>').find('tr:first'))).DataTable({
                    "paging": true,
                    "ordering": false,
                    "info": false,
                    "pageLength": 10,
                    "bLengthChange": false,
                });
                var PageVal = localStorage.getItem("PageNum");
                if (PageVal == null) {
                    PageVal = 0;
                }
                if (PageVal >= 1) {
                    PageVal = PageVal - 1;
                }
                if (PageVal == "") {
                    PageVal = 0;
                }


                table.page(PageVal).draw('page');            
                localStorage.removeItem("PageNum");
                table.columns().every(function () {
                    var that = this;
                    $('input', this.header()).on('keyup change', function () {
                        if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                            that
                                .search(this.value).draw();
                        }
                    });
                });

            };
            function SearchValue(values) {
                if (values != null || values != "") {
                    if (typeof values !== "undefined") {
                        var i = values[0];
                        $('#txtElement').val(i);
                        var j = values[1];
                        $('#txtName').val(j);
                        var k = values[2];
                        $('#txtName').val(k);

                        table.columns().every(function () {
                            var that = this;
                            $('input', this.header()).load('keyup change', function () {
                                if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                                    that
                                        .search(this.value).draw();
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    }
                }
            };


            var idClicked;
            $(function () {
                $('#<%=TextBoxContainer.ClientID %>').click(function (e) {
                    idClicked = "Clicked";
                    var info = table.page.info();
                    var currPag = info.page + 1;
                    var All = info.pages;

                    if (currPag != 0 || currPag <= All) {
                        localStorage.setItem("PageNum", "");
                        localStorage.setItem("PageNum", currPag);
                        localStorage.setItem("Info", "Clicked");
                    }
                });
            });

        </script>
```

Comment: Add a style when you find the word?

Comment: Hi @Interactive, please tell me how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example of how you do it.

```js
var text = $("#textBox").html();
var word = "it";
var wordRegExp = new RegExp("it", "gi");
text = text.replace(wordRegExp, '<span class="highlighted">' + word + '</span>');
$("body").html(text);
```

```css
.highlighted {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="textBox">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi @Abdelaziz Mokhnache, how can i apply to my code your answer please tell me. where i place the `<span>`

Comment: surely it will not work as it is. you have to replace `#textBox` with the `id` of your search results container and `word` with the word you are searching for.

Comment: i am not found where the word so i am asking you to please help me me alos want to change to my code

Comment: I am a javascript developer. Sorry I can not understand you asp code. do search functionality works correctly for ?

Comment: I am taking search functionality and all in `<script>` tag front end. Your code will work but my code search element value i didn't found that is the problem for me thank you

Comment: are you searching in the same page, or in a database via the server ?

Comment: here i am taking jquery Datatable plugin for searching